# Removing words from strings within a column dataframe

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Num           Text 
1        15 March 2020 - There was...
2        15 March 2020 - There has been...
3        24 April 2018 - Nothing has ...
4        07 November 2014 - The Kooks....
...
```

I would like to remove the first 4 words from each rows in Text (i.e. `15 March 2020 - , 15 March 2020 -,`...). 
I tried with

`df['Text']=df['Text'].str.replace(' ', )` but I do not know what I should include in the brackets to replace those values with an empty space (or just nothing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`df.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`df.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html).

```
df['test'].str.split(n=4).str[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using **[`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):**

Considering your df to be:

```
In [1193]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Num':[1,2,3,4], 'Text':['15 March 2020 - There was','15 March 2020 - There has been','24 April 2018 - Nothing has','07 November 2014 - The Kooks']})

In [1194]: df
Out[1194]: 
   Num                            Text
0    1       15 March 2020 - There was
1    2  15 March 2020 - There has been
2    3     24 April 2018 - Nothing has
3    4    07 November 2014 - The Kooks

In [1207]: df['Text'].str.split().str[4:].apply(' '.join)                                                                                                                                                
Out[1207]: 
0         There was
1    There has been
2       Nothing has
3         The Kooks
Name: Text, dtype: object
```

Comment: there is a problem with `-` as I can have also other `-` in the text. How could I drop only the first 4 words?

Comment: @LucaDiMauro Try my answer see if it works for you.

Comment: @LucaDiMauro Handled. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @MayankPorwal `str.split` by default splits at whitespace it's redundant to use `str.split(' ')` and it has parameter `n` which splits upto n times instead of splitting at every whitespace. Instead of using `apply(' '.join)` use `pd.Series.str.join`

Comment: @Ch3steR Agreed. Updated the answer. THanks

Answer (score 0):

What might work is using the split command to split it into words and then take the anything after the 4th word using [4:]

Answer (score 0):

Python can implement different regex and example could be for four words `str.replace("\d* \d* \d* \d*", '')` here is a [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) to learn more about python regex and how to detect different patterns in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is less elegant, I prefer to use ".find()" with an ".apply()". Whatever happen the ".find" the first "-" will be taken as delimiter.

```
t = pd.DataFrame({'Num':[1,2,3,4], 'Text':['15 March 2020 - There was','15 March 2020 - There has been','24 April 2018 - Nothing has','07 November 2014 - The Kooks']})

t["text2"] = t.apply(lambda x: x['Text'][str(x['Text']).find("- ")+2:], axis=1)
```

This :

```
Num           Text 
1        15 March 2020 - There was...
2        15 March 2020 - There has been...
3        24 April 2018 - Nothing has ...
4        07 November 2014 - The Kooks....
```

Become this :

```
   Num                            Text           text2
0    1       15 March 2020 - There was       There was
1    2  15 March 2020 - There has been  There has been
2    3     24 April 2018 - Nothing has     Nothing has
3    4    07 November 2014 - The Kooks       The Kooks
```